# MySQL throws "java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
String QueryText= "INSERT INTO user_details (fname,lname,user_email,birth_day,birth_mnth,birth_year,addr,pwd) VALUES ('"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+user_email+"','"+birth_day+"','"+birth_mnth+"','"+birth_year+"','"+gender+"','"+addr+"','"+pwd+"')";

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jspdatabase", "root","");

Statement st=con.createStatement();

int rt = st.executeUpdate(QueryText);
```

Comment: well, 8 != 9 ...

Comment: Learn to use parameters.  That prevents all sorts of problems.  And, they make the code easier to read and update.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid problem as this gender and SQL Injection it's better to use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead :

```
String queryText = "INSERT INTO user_details "
      + "(fname, lname, user_email, birth_day, birth_mnth, birth_year, gender, addr, pwd) "
      //----------------------------------------------------------------^
      + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                      "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jspdatabase", "root", "");

try(PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(queryText);){
    pst.setString(1, fname);
    pst.setString(2, lname);
    pst.setString(3, user_email);
    pst.setString(4, birth_day);   //If one of the three is integer type
    pst.setString(5, birth_mnth);  //You have to use setInt(...) instead
    pst.setString(6, birth_year);  //of setString(...)
    pst.setString(7, gender);
    pst.setString(8, addr);
    pst.setString(9, pwd);
    int rt = pst.executeUpdate();
    ...
}
```

---

The real problem is that you are using 8 parameters and try to insert 9 values this is why you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear the number of column doesn't match the values you provide.

You declare 8 columns and provide 9 values.

Gender isn't declared in your columns